# How to Convert Excel File To CSV ( Comma Separated values) File in SSIS Package

Tags: excel, ssis, netezza, ssis-2008

I need to import the excel data into netezza using SSIS. There are some columns where my first 100-200 rows are blank and due to which I am getting Null as an output for that columns. 
I need to have my output as  0 's for the columns(which are only decimal and numeric datatype) where the rows are empty and ' '(blank) for the columns(Varchar, char datatype) where the rows are empty.

The only way I believe is using script task and would appreciate if anyone can share the script.

If there are any better solution for this type of problem without changing in excel property then please share it.

Comment: Have you tried adding a Derived Column task that transforms the nulls in each column as you describe?

Comment: And why not just set a default value in the destination table in netezza?

Comment: Just adding on to what Jeremy has said. The best solution in this process is to just add a derived column with a null check expression. e.g. ISNULL( [F1]) || [F1] == "" ? (DT_WSTR,30) 0 : [F1] where F1 is your column name. Appropriately cast it depending on the type of the column.